# Read Xbee serial number with Arduino

Tags: arduino, xbee

I plan to have several Arduino boards connected to XBee series 2 radios in the same network performing the same operation. They are to transmit data to another board that will upload all of the data at once using a cellular connection. I would like to uniquely identify each board in some way. I realize I can hardcode a serial number into the EEPROM memory of the Arduino board. However that will not scale very well for what I am trying to do. Is there a way to read the XBee's serial number using Arduino code, so that I can transmit it along with my data?

```
string serialnumber
volatile int IRQcount1;
volatile int IRQcount2;
int pin2 = 2;
int pin3 = 3;
int pin_irq1 = 0; //IRQ that matches to pin 2
int pin_irq2 = 1; //IRQ that matches to pin 3

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void IRQcounter1() {
  IRQcount1++;
}

void IRQcounter2() {
  IRQcount2++;
}

// I would like some function to get the serial number here

void get_xbee_serial() {
}

void loop() {
  attachInterrupt(pin_irq1, IRQcounter1, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(pin_irq2, IRQcounter2, RISING);
  delay(25);
  detachInterrupt(pin2);
  detachInterrupt(pin3);
  Serial.print(F("Xbee Serial Number = "));
  Serial.print(serialnumber);
  Serial.print(F("     Counter 1 = "));      
  Serial.print(IRQcount1);
  Serial.print(F("     Counter 2 = "));   
  Serial.println(IRQcount2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the serial number using the AT commands `ATSH` and `ATSL` (serial number high/low).  You can do that by going into command mode, sending those sequences followed by a return, and parsing the responses.

To get into command mode, you need to wait 1 second without sending anything, send the escape sequence `+++`, and then wait another second.  The XBee module should respond with `OK\r` indicating that it's ready to receive commands.

Send `ATSH\r` and you should get a hex string representing the top four bytes of the serial number.  Repeat with `ATSL\r` for the bottom four bytes.

And know that if you use a destination address of `0`, the XBee module will automatically send data to the coordinator on your network.  If the coordinator is running in API mode, it can retrieve the sender's 64-bit MAC address from the frame header of the received data.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. Especially the part about retrieving the MAC addresses. I will look into that as it seems like it may be the best solution for my project.

Comment: Is it likely that one could purchase two XBee radios with the same low serial number? Just curious.

Comment: Unlikely.  I believe all 802.15.4-based XBee modules (including ZigBee and DigiMesh) have the same `SH` value, though.